# How to use @id in $resource object in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-factory, angularjs-resource

I am using $resource in angularjs to call my rails api and when i call this route using angularjs $resource object like this

```
.factory('playlists',['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource("/events/:id/playlists", {id: "@id"},{
        query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
    })
}]);
```

I am calling this query method from  controller like this

```
$scope.playlists = playlists.query();
```

It is actually calling only

```
/events/playlists
```

I don't know why :id is not replacing with proper event_id

Comment: how you calling the method, it should be called using  `playlists.get({ id: 1})`

Comment: @PankajParkar thanks it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get that parameter reflect into the URL you need to pass that parameter while calling `$resource` get method

```
playlists.get({ id: 1})
```